# How to getDefinitionByName of a packageless class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, actionscript, introspection

Say you have a flexunit test that looks like this:

```
package foo {
    import flexunit.framework.TestCase;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName;
    class DescribeTypeTest {
      public function testDescribeInnerType():void {
        var currentInstance:ChildBar = new ChildBar();
        trace(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(currentInstance)));
      }
    }
}
class Bar{}
class ChildBar extends Bar{}
```

Which throws the exception "Error #1065: Variable Bar is not defined." It only applies to inner classes (classes outside the package).

Does anyone have any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is any workaround, but just to confirm:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName():

> getDefinitionByName   ()  function
>   public function
>   getDefinitionByName(name:String):Object
>   Language Version :    ActionScript 3.0
>   Runtime Versions :    AIR 1.0, Flash
>   Player 9 Returns a reference to the
>   class object of the class specified by
>   the name parameter.
>
> Parameters
>
> name:String — The name of a class.
>   Returns Object — Returns a reference
>   to the class object of the class
>   specified by the name parameter.
>
> **Throws ReferenceError — No public
>   definition exists with the specified
>   name.**

Since both Bar and ChildBar are non-public, you're getting that ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested following code with Flex 3.3 (AIR app):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="t();">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.describeType;
            import flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName;
            private function t():void {
                trace(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(new FooBar())));
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Bar.as

```
package
{
    public class Bar
    {
    }
}
```

FooBar.as

```
package
{
    public class FooBar extends Bar
    {
        public function FooBar()
        {
            super();
        }        
    }
}
```

As a trace result I see:

```
[SWF] DefTest.swf - 1,024,228 bytes after decompression
[class Bar]
```

Can you confirm this? Does that helps?

Comment: Can't be inside the package. The point is to load private (packageless) classes.